# How is 90/180 day rule enforced when traveller has a German residence permit?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, international-travel, germany, schengen-visas, 90-180-visa-rules

I am an Australian citizen with a German residence permit (type D) valid for 12 months.

My residence permit allows me to spend 90 days out of 180 days travelling within the Schengen zone (outside of Germany).

My question is the following:

**How is this 90/180 day rule enforced? How do authorities track/trace/know when a traveller with a residence permit has spent more than 90 days travelling in other Schengen countries? Surely they have *some* way of enforcing this?**

Normally 90/180 day rule can be enforced by looking at a travellers passport, however, when the traveller has a residence permit, the dates in the passport are of no use.

**When it finally comes to the point of leaving the EU, do German authorities expect you to provide proof that you didn't spend more than the legal amount of time travelling in other Schengen countries? If so, what sort of documents can be used as proof?**

Comment: See also https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/158295/how-do-schengen-countries-know-if-someone-has-overstayed-internally

Comment: As a permanent resident you are **trusted** not to abuse the Schengen travel privilege. Anything else would require controls on the citizens as well, which are not supposed to happen (unless there is a refugee crisis or a pandemic). There will be consequences if violations are caught by accident, e.g. during a tax audit. It might be smart to keep records of any international travel within the Schengen area, e.g. hotel bills or airline tickets.